$f(z) = P(z)P(wz)P(w^2z) $ has coefficients vanish for $z^k$ when $k$ mod $3 \neq 0$, where w is a cube root of unity, $w^2 + w +1 = 0$
Let $ w $ be a primitive cube root of unity such that $ w^2 + w + 1 = 0$.
Consider a polynomial $ P(z)$ defined as:
$$
P(z) = a_n z^n + a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 z + a_0
$$
We define the polynomial:
$$
f(z) = P(z) P(wz) P(w^2z)
$$
We want to show that $ f(z) $ has coefficients equal to zero for all non-cubic powers of $ z $.
That is, the $k$th coefficient of $ f(z) $; $ b_k = 0 $ if $k$ is not divisible by $3$.
Here's my approach so far:

We expressed the coefficient of $ z^k$ in $ f(z) $ as:

$$
\text{Coefficient of } z^k = \sum_{k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = k} a_{k_1} a_{k_2} a_{k_3} w^{3k_1 + k_2 + 2k_3}
$$

We analyze the sum over all permutations of $ (k_1, k_2, k_3) $:

$$
S = \sum_{\text{permutations}} a_{k_1} a_{k_2} a_{k_3} w^{3k_1 + k_2 + 2k_3}
$$

For fixed $k$, the non $w$ coefficients are equal.  We factor out  $w^k = w^{k_1 + k_2 + k_3}$:

$$
S = w^k \sum_{\text{permutations}} a_{k_1} a_{k_2} a_{k_3} w^{(2k_1 + k_3)}
$$

We thus get six terms in power of $w$ that are symmetric. We have to show that these form two pairs of the sum

$$ 1 + w + w^2 = 0, $$
unless $ k $ is a multiple of $3$, and every power of $w$ reduces to unity.
I am stuck at evaluating the contributions from the terms in the symmetric permutation cancel out and to demonstrate that all non-cubic powered coefficients must equal zero.

Write $f(z)=\sum b_i z^i$. We have $f(\omega z) = f(z)$ by construction, which implies
$$
\sum b_i z^i = \sum b_i \omega^i z^i
$$
Since this is an equality between polynomials, we may equate coefficients, which means that $b_i = 0$ for all $i$ such that $\omega^i \neq 1$, i.e. for all $i$ such that $3 \nmid i$.

Thank you, this was clear and concise!

It is easier to use that
$$
  f(wz) = p(wz)p(z^2z)p(w^3z) = f(z) \, .
$$
If $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k z^k$ is the power series of $f$ then
$$
 f(wz) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty w^kb_n z^k = f(z)
$$
implies that $w^k b_k = b_k$ for all $k$, since the coefficients of a power series are uniquely determined.
It follows that $b_k = 0$ if $w^k \ne 1$, that is if $k$ is not divisible by $3$.
Remark: The same argument works if the polynomial $P$ is replaced by a power series with positive radius of convergence (or equivalently, by a function which is holomorphic in some disk $B_R(0)$, $0 < R \le \infty$).

If $p$ was not given to be a polynomial, but just infinitely differentiable, then this power series method applies? I'm just unsure how we are comparing terms in a power series, can't distinct series converge to the same value?

@AlanDSouza: Yes, this works with all power series which have a positive radius of convergence. There is an “identity theorem for power series” which states that the coefficients of power series are uniquely determined.

I see, thank you for your answer.

There is an easier way to see this. Notice that $$f(\omega^2 z)=f(\omega z)=f(z)$$ we therefore have $$f(z)=\frac{f(z)+f(\omega z)+f(\omega^2 z)}{3}$$ the last sum consists of the terms of $f$ having degree a multiple of $3$.
